# How to initiate a form that locates on all pages of Spring-MVC?

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, tiles-3

I need to have a search box on all pages of my website. I know, to have a form I need to initiate it like following method;however, it is useful if user gets to "/search" address, how can I initiate a form that is in all pages like [searchbox of tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.au/TravelersChoice) that is located on all pages ? should I call the method all the time?

**Sample initialize method**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(Model model) {
    if (!model.containsAttribute(BINDING_RESULT_NAME)) {
        model.addAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME, new Search());
    }
    return "search";
}
```

**Current form**

My current form looks like following:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="search" role="form" method="GET">
.....
</form:form>
```

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I am using tiles3 does that do the job? whats your idea about Rembo's answer?

Comment: tiles has some limitations compared to sitemesh. i'd go w sitemesh 2.4 as that's what grails uses and there's more documentation

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan as I do not know sitemesh much would takes longer to learn, if I want to do it with tiles how would that work? should I have the form in a separate jsp and include that? Whats your idea about Rembo's answer?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose that your form is included in a page called `search.jsp`, you might include it in other pages just putting:

```
<%@ include file="search.jsp" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> how can I initiate a form that is in all pages like searchbox of
>   tripadvisor that is located on all pages ?

Use [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) to add model binding object like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
class GlobalControllerHandler {

   @ModelAttribute(ATTRIBUTE_NAME)
   public Search bindSearchModel(){
       return new Search();    
   } 
}
```

In this case `@ModelAttribute` methods that apply to all @RequestMapping methods. then your current form will work fine.

Comment: Whats your idea about sitemesh or using tiles3?

Answer (score 0):

I just manually added the action attribute to the form and it works now. Thanks for your help.